# Excel, VBA Editor - Autocomplete for the Worksheet object's properties doesn't work

Tags: excel, autocomplete, excel-2007, vba

I want the VBA Editor to use the Autocomplete feature to display the properties of the Worksheet object.

[image]

---

Out of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/567461/in-excel-2007-in-vba-editor-why-when-i-type-worksheets1-excel-does-not-li) question on SuperUser, I've learned that the `Worksheets` object `Item()` property returns the Variant type. That type is not strongly typed to the `Worksheet` object.

But, even if I use the `ActiveSheet` object or the following code, the IDE still does not display the properties of the `Worksheet` object.

[image]

My question is, how to make the VBA Editor in Excel to display the properties of the Worksheet object through the Autocomplete feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kindly declare mySheet variable as worksheet to get autocompletion.Please refer to the below image.

[image]